# MySQL with JDBC: select * from mysql.proc => FUNCTION * does not exist

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

MySQL with JDBC:

```
select * from mysql.proc
________________________
    PreparedStatement selectClientIDsStatement = null;
    Connection connection = Db.getConnection();
    try {
        String query = "select * from mysql.proc";
        selectClientIDsStatement = connection.prepareCall(query);
        ...exception
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new VeException(e);
    } finally {...
    }
```

=> FUNCTION * does not exist
But Workbench gives normal result. Why it is like this?

Comment: Please show your code, not only the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a strange error message - I just tried this with mysql-connector-java-5.1.34 (against  5.5.42 MySQL Community Server) and it worked (no exception, but also no rows returned)...

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MySQL {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?user=root&password=root");

        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from mysql.proc");

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            System.out.println("GOT A ROW!");
        }

        resultSet.close();
        statement.close();
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

Does your query string contain hard spaces or anything??

UPDATE

It looks like you are using `prepareCall` instead of `prepareStatement`

Comment: @ArthurKharkivskiy Why `prepareCall`? Why not `createStatement` or `prepareStatement`?